# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). pandas python using NOT IN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am getting The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). pandas python when i used the NOT IN operator in python

her

```
filter= ['x','y',''z]
df = pd.read(SOME CSV HERE)

df.drop(df[df['column name'] not in filter].index, inplace=True)
```

what seems to be the problem?
how do i fix this?

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to drop columns that are in filter or keep them?

Answer (score 1):

You would better use .isin method:

```
df.drop(df[~(df['column name'].isin(filter))].index, inplace=True)
```

If you want to keep the rows that are in filter you can use df.query():

```
df.query("column_name in @filter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the `not in` condition? You can simply just filter directly from the list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
f = ['a','c','d']
```

#### KEEPING COLUMNS THAT ARE IN FILTER

```
out1 = df[f]
print(out1)
```

```
          a         c         d
0  0.639544  0.948477  0.587575
1  0.766207  0.637332  0.830189
2  0.219860  0.100648  0.891352
3  0.653428  0.843172  0.019700
4  0.986800  0.644410  0.714347
```

#### REMOVING COLUMNS THAT ARE IN FILTER

```
out2 = df.drop(f, axis=1)
print(out2)
```

```
          b         e
0  0.492916  0.534971
1  0.167386  0.381723
2  0.419879  0.708026
3  0.536441  0.773500
4  0.015564  0.999838
```